# Javascript error in IE8: 'type' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error in IE8 only. 
The complete error is

```
     'type' is null or not an object      jQuery, line 226 character 4526
```

The code is obfuscated but looking at the surrounding code I could track the failure to globalize.js line 581
https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/lib/globalize.js

Now I do not see any 'type' object/variable in this code. Also I could not understand the meaning of this error.
Can anyone explain what is this error with steps how to reproduce this error in chrome console via test code? 
Can anyone tell me what could be happening incorrectly in IE8? This works fine in chrome, ff, IE9, safari.
Thanks.

Comment: The real problem is in some code that **calls** something in jQuery.

Comment: Do debugging only with non-minified scripts.